# Get xml response instead of json

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, json

I'm using jquery ajax call to my web service:

```
$.ajax({
    type: sType,
    url: "myWebService.asmx",
    cache: serviceCash,
    data: params,
    accepts: {
        text: "application/json"
    },
    contentType: contentType,
    dataType: "json"
    ....
```

Web service looks like:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetLang(string cLang, string iLangVersion ){
//code to create json string
return jsonResp;
}
```

When i have type: POST evertyhing works perfect.

```
type: "POST",
data: "{ 'clang':'ANG', 'iLangVersion' : '1'}",
contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
dataType: "json"
```

The response is pure json :

```
{"d":"{\"userSettingsData\":{\" ...and so on
```

When i change request to GET method:

```
type: "GET",
data: "clang=ANG&iLangVersion=1",
contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
dataType: "json"
```

The response is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"translation":"\r\n{\"translation\":{\"..and so on
```

What should i change to get response in json format as before?
So, I'm sending url encoded data to the web service and in return I want to get json and not XML! 
I have defined dataType: "json" - The type of data that you're expecting back from the server
I have set accepted type: accepts: {text: "application/json"} -  tells the server what kind of response it will accept in return.

But i get xml in return. What should I change?

Comment: It would all depend on the server side API's. Contact the developers for details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have control over the script that sends the return you should post that code. If you do not have control over that script then your best bet is to set dataType: "xml" in your post request and handle it that way.

You cant really force XML over to JSON without doing it from the script that handles your request.

Comment: Well, if request is GET (not POST) i think it is not possible to force  server to return json with request headers. Only way I have found is directly go into Context object. Otherwise, It will always return xml.
So, one option is to parse xml on client and get json from xml.
Other option I have tried:
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Write jsonObject
    Return;

But I get enter sign(or something similar) as first and last character in ws response.
How can I remove that?

Comment: If the server is returning XML it is no way to FORCE it to return JSON without parsing the XML first.

If i create a script that i set to return "Hello", i cant force it to return something else through javascript, id have to change it in the script itself.

Comment: Slugge, I'm talking about web service(server) script.
I have this header with my web service
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

and i return json string at the end of web service.
But the response will be wrapped into xml anyway. 
If you call web service by GET method, the response is always xml, only POST methods will get response as json. The only way around I have found is to clear current response and write by your own, as I have mentioned. But I get one additional character(enter I think) in front and end of json response, which breaks json parser.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the server side process is written, but in the first chunk of code you are telling the server that you want a JSON response:

```
accepts: {
    text: "application/json"
},
```

Presumably that will work if you add it to the second request too.

Failing that, you will need to examine the server side code more closely to see what logic it uses to determine the response type.